# How to get hat enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, brackets

How can I define a command that would put hat with parenthesis over its argument? The command has to work in a math mode. I know that question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297851/how-to-get-tilde-enclosed-in-parenthesis) but I did not manage to modify any of the proposed solutions to fit my problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Linespacing will be badly affected if you use this inline, but you could make a new accent with the `accents` package. To get the spacing within the parentheses right I used `trimbox` from the `trimclip` package to remove whitespace below the `^`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\phat}[1]{{\accentset{(\!\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\ensuremath{\string^}}\!)}{#1}}}

\begin{document}    

$\phat{A}$

\end{document}
```

For a wider hat, you could use `\scalebox` with a horizontal (but not vertical) stretch factor. Here it is set to 2:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\phat}[1]{{\accentset{(\!\!\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\scalebox{2}[1]{\ensuremath{\string^}}}\!\!)}{#1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible, though, to make the "hat" wider?

Comment: @wedelfach: You could use `\scalebox{1.5}[1]{\ensuremath{\string^}}` (or any stretch factor you want).